# delete custom post based on custom field date

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-status

### RESOLVED ## updated code below.

I had created custom post type called 'esitykset' and I wanted to delete them if they are older that the date in 'show_date' custom field of the post.

So I tried the following code

```
 add_action( 'wp', 'expire_events_daily' );
function expire_events_daily() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'delete_expired_events' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'delete_expired_events');
    }
}
add_action( 'delete_expired_events', 'delete_expired_events_callback' );


function delete_expired_events_callback() 
{
    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'esitykset',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields'         => 'ids', //only get post id's
        'meta_query'     => [
            [
               'key'     => 'show_date',
               'value'   => current_time( 'Y/m/d' ),
               'compare' => '<'
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $events = get_posts( $args );

    if ( $events ) {
        // Loop through the post ID's and delete the post
        foreach ( $events as $id )
            wp_trash_post( $id );
    }
}
```

For the code above to work, I had to add

```
define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);
```

in my wp-config.php file.

Now it worked. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: What is the format in which the date is saved in your custom field. Also, `time()` returns a unix timestamp. If your dates in your custom field is not saved as unix timestamp, thing will never work. Your date/time formats should be in the same exact format. Also note, for this to work, if your dates are not saved in unix, the format have to be `year month day`, any other format will not work

Comment: Hello Pieter, the date is saved in YYYY/MM/DD format. I believe it is a Unix timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a date format mismatch here. You say your dates are saved as `Y/m/d` in your custom field, which is correct, but then you try to match this format to [unix timestamp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (*which is the result from `time()`*).

Date and time formats need to be in exactly the same format in order to match or to compare two different dates in a custom field, this is how custom fields work. There is no logic to know and no logic to convert and match different date/time formats, so you  will need to manually make sure that everything matches up.

Instead of using `time()` to return the current date/time and using that as date/time comparison, you should use [`current_time( 'Y/m/d' )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time). Just a note, this is only possible as from WordPress 3.9

Just another note, we can simplify your function as follow, which will be faster and better for performance (*NOTE: Requires PHP 5.4 at least*)

```
function delete_expired_events_callback() 
{
    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'esitykset',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields'         => 'ids', //only get post id's
        'meta_query'     => [
            [
               'key'     => 'show_date',
               'value'   => current_time( 'Y/m/d' ),
               'compare' => '<'
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $events = get_posts( $args );

    if ( $events ) {
        // Loop through the post ID's and delete the post
        foreach ( $events as $id )
            wp_delete_post( $id );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pieter, thanks but this code. I simply copied and pasted it and still didn't work. I am wondering if i wp_schedule_eventis working at all. Do you knwo if it could be some other problem?

Comment: Hi Pieter, I'd really appreciate if you could help me with this. I have updated the code I am running my child theme's functions.php

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/147785/31545). Also, make 100% sure that your formats for your dates are matching up

Comment: Thanks Pieter. You were right, I added `define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);` to my wp-config.php file and it worked. I am updating the code above.